# How to disable snapview in WINJS?

Tags: winjs

I am creating an app in which snapview should be disabled.I have tried using:

```
 window.addEventListener("resize", onViewStateChanged);
       function onViewStateChanged(eventArgs) {
           var viewStates = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState;
           var newViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
           if (newViewState === 2 || newViewState===3) {
               showMenu('snapped');
           } 
       }
       function showMenu(event) {
           //Detect View State
           if (event === 'snapped') {
               var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(
       "Resizing Window");
               msg.showAsync();
               window.innerWidth=screen.width

           }
```

But this doesn't seem to work.Is there anything that i might have missed to disable the snapview.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you're talking about snapped view, I assume that you're targeting Windows 8.0 and not Windows 8.1. In the latter, the snapped view state was removed in favor of variable-sized views, and in the app manifest you can indicate a minimum width of 500px (the default) or 320px (the former snapped view). Leaving it to 500px will prevent the narrow snapped view altogether.

If you are yet targeting Windows 8.0, there is unfortunately no means to disable snapped view (which is, by the way, why the change happened for 8.1). Apps that cannot effectively operate in the 320px view just display a message to that effect, suggesting to the user that they resize the view to use the app.